# Select returning values from filter if no row found

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I need a select statement which always returns at least one record. Something like this

```
SELECT id, date FROM mytable WHERE id = <INPUT_ID> AND date = <INPUT_DATE>
UNION ALL
SELECT VALUE_FROM_FILTER(id), VALUE_FROM_FILTER(date) WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = <INPUT_ID> AND date = <INPUT_DATE>)
```

So should the query return 0 rows, it returns at least one row with the input values.
Is this possible in SQL?

I'm using Oracle 10.2

`<INPUT_ID>` and `<INPUT_DATE>` is just a replacement for any unknown values

(based on answers and comments I modified the question to be more obvious)

Comment: If you have the input values stored in variables you can just run SELECT [@var1], [@var2], [@var3] and not include any table.  This can be the first row of your union and you'll always return it.

Comment: Please note that the brackets around the variable names are just to get around StackOverflow thinking I'm trying to notify people

Comment: Unfortunatelly I don't have it in variables. The query is text-parsed. The application takes the pattern query, replace {WHERE} with real filter and then execute it. But I don't have access to that app, I can just edit the query pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can predicate the "default' row on the fact that the first query returns no results:

```
SELECT id, date FROM mytable WHERE id = @INPUT_ID AND date = @INPUT_DATE
UNION
SELECT @INPUT_ID AS id, @INPUT_DATE AS date FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = @INPUT_ID AND date = @INPUT_DATE)
```

Comment: But I cannot access the values in filter in this way. The query is just plain-text. Maybe I should modify the question to be more clear. But the predicate is good idea, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure I follow, but I *think* this does what you want:

```
with t as (select <INPUT ID> as input_id, <INPUT DATE> as input_date from dual)
select input_id, input_date
from t
left join mytable mt on mt.id = t.input_id and mt.date = t.input_date;
```

With some sample data:

```
create table mytable (id number, date_fld date);
insert into mytable (id, date_fld) values (1, date '2013-04-24');
insert into mytable (id, date_fld) values (2, date '2013-04-22');
insert into mytable (id, date_fld) values (2, date '2013-04-22');
insert into mytable (id, date_fld) values (2, date '2013-04-23');
```

... and queries:

```
with t as (select 1 as input_id, date '2013-04-21' as input_date from dual)
select input_id, input_date
from t
left join mytable mt on mt.id = t.input_id and mt.date_fld = t.input_date;

  INPUT_ID INPUT_DAT
---------- ---------
         1 21-APR-13

with t as (select 1 as input_id, date '2013-04-24' as input_date from dual)
select input_id, input_date
from t
left join mytable mt on mt.id = t.input_id and mt.date_fld = t.input_date;

  INPUT_ID INPUT_DAT
---------- ---------
         1 24-APR-13

with t as (select 2 as input_id, date '2013-04-22' as input_date from dual)
select input_id, input_date
from t
left join mytable mt on mt.id = t.input_id and mt.date_fld = t.input_date;

  INPUT_ID INPUT_DAT
---------- ---------
         2 22-APR-13
         2 22-APR-13
```

Now I've typed that in I've got a nasty feeling I'm answering the wrong question, and you really want to transform the `{WHERE}` into a new query that does this. The interaction between the query and the application isn't very clear to me I'm afraid.

Comment: Yea, I think I haven't explained it well. I don't know what data will the application request. So I cannot select anything specific. I need something like this: `SELECT VALUE_FROM_FILTER(id), VALUE_FROM_FILTER(date)`

Comment: @karel - I was afraid you'd say that. If all you have is the `where` clause then that suggests it needs to be parsed and the relevant values extracted, which isn't trivial. Do you even know how many conditions will be in the `where` clause, or if both fixed fields will be present? If there's a limited range of possible values and both will be present it can be hacked I guess, but not prettily. I guess I find the requirement odd - it ought to be up to the app to deal with getting no data, I'd have thought..

Comment: You're right it could be possible to parse the condition to get the values (the condition format is fixed). The application puts the condition wherever finds string `{WHERE}` so I can place this `{WHERE}` inside of some REGEXP_SUBSTR directly in columns within the default `SELECT`. I'll try - thanks for tip!

Comment: @karel - if the condition format is fixed, makes me wonder why it's done dynamically, and they aren't just running a query and binding the input values (which would make this solution work *8-) instead of replacing the whole `where` clause. I probably don't want to know, come to think of it. Incidentally, you'll get more eyes on the question if you tag it with 'oracle' as well as (or instead of) 'oracle10g'.